# Text Column Validation of 3 letters and 9 numbers

Tags: sharepoint-online

I'm pretty new to this and I can't find any specific example on how to validate the lenght of a field (12) The first 3 positions are letters and the next 9 numbers. For example: ABC123456789. They don't have to be capital letters.

I tried this by piecing together a few different things but I'm honestly totally lost.
AND(LEN(ColumnName)=12, LEFT(ColumnName,3)=[A-Z], ISNUMBER(0+MID(ColumnName,4,9)))

Your help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you both for your help in solving this puzzle. I used both of your examples to help me piece this together.

```
=AND(LEN([ColumnName])=12,AND(LEFT([ColumnName],1)>="a",LEFT([ColumnName],1)<="z",AND(MID([ColumnName],2,1)>="a",MID([ColumnName],2,1)<="z",AND(MID([ColumnName],3,1)>="a",MID([ColumnName],3,1)<="z",ISNUMBER(0+MID([ColumnName],4,9))))))
```

This example verifies that the column has 12 characters, that positions 1, 2, 3 are each within A-Z and that the 4-9 Are numbers.

I learned a lot during this process. The links to articles were very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

The field validation formulas are more or less excel functions. So, I would suggest you to try your formulas in excel first.

you will probably end up with something like this (assuming your data are in cell B1):

```
=AND(LEN(B1)=12, ISTEXT(LEFT(B1,3)), ISNUMBER(0+MID(B1,4,9)))
```

(It seems that the "ISTEXT" in SP is not behaving as expected.
helpfull articles about these functions can be found [here.](https://techtrainingnotes.blogspot.com/2015/10/sharepoint-column-validation-examples.html) and [here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/examples-of-common-formulas-in-lists-d81f5f21-2b4e-45ce-b170-bf7ebf6988b3))

And of course you need to replace B1 with your column name.

good luck,

d.

Comment: Thank you for this solution it works to ensure that they don't add special characters but it still doesn't let me verify to ensure that the first 3 characters are only letters. But for now I will most definately use this to help limit the data.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the following formula:

```
 =IF(AND(LEN(Test)=12,OR(AND(CODE(MID(Test,1,1))>96,CODE(MID(Test,1,1))<123),AND(CODE(MID(Test,1,1))>64,CODE(MID(Test,1,1))<91)),OR(AND(CODE(MID(Test,2,1))>96,CODE(MID(Test,2,1))<123),AND(CODE(MID(Test,2,1))>64,CODE(MID(Test,2,1))<91)),OR(AND(CODE(MID(Test,3,1))>96,CODE(MID(Test,3,1))<123),AND(CODE(MID(Test,3,1))>64,CODE(MID(Test,3,1))<91)),CODE(MID(Test,4,1))>47,CODE(MID(Test,4,1))<58,CODE(MID(Test,5,1))>47,CODE(MID(Test,5,1))<58,CODE(MID(Test,6,1))>47,CODE(MID(Test,6,1))<58,CODE(MID(Test,7,1))>47,CODE(MID(Test,7,1))<58,CODE(MID(Test,8,1))>47,CODE(MID(Test,8,1))<58,CODE(MID(Test,9,1))>47,CODE(MID(Test,9,1))<58,CODE(MID(Test,10,1))>47,CODE(MID(Test,10,1))<58,CODE(MID(Test,11,1))>47,CODE(MID(Test,11,1))<58,CODE(MID(Test,12,1))>47,CODE(MID(Test,12,1))<58),TRUE,FALSE)
```

As a result, the validation runs normally:
[image]

[image]

**Notice:Per my test, if we use "12" as the column name, we need to replace "Test" in the formula with "[12]".**

---

If the answer is helpful, please click "√" on the left panel of the answer and kindly upvote it.

Comment: Thank you for the reply but it apperas I got lost in this statement. Where in the statement do we test to ensure that position 1,2,3 are only letters?

Comment: Use this formula:
=IF(AND(LEN(Test)=1,OR(AND(CODE(MID(Test,1,1))>96,CODE(MID(Test,1,1))<123),AND(CODE(MID(Test,1,1))>64,CODE(MID(Test,1,1))<91))),TRUE,FALSE), you could ensure that the position 1 is only letter, and the position 2,3 are same.